# Google Cloud Storage free tier has "5 GB-months" is but min bucket is 10 GB

Tags: google-cloud-storage

I am using the free tier to learn if Google Cloud Compute will suit my needs.

I don't understand the Storage free tier. I find nothing in Google support to explain.

-- "5 GB-months" is free. But minimum bucket size 10 G.
-- So I can't have ANY persistent storage in the free tier, correct?
-- I can only use it half the month and then delete?

Comment: Where do you see a minimum bucket size of 10G?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Cloud Storage Free Usage Limits](https://cloud.google.com/storage/pricing#cloud-storage-always-free) are well documented. There is no mention of a 10 GB minimum.

Comment: Thank you for the link. I recall seeing a 10GB min when I created the first bucket, but I don't see that anywhere now. 

An empty bucket is zero GB? The size is actual usage, not potential?

Is that correct?

Comment: Correct, it's actual and it's based on time. 1G stored for a day is 1G-day. You get 5 GB-months (5 GB stored for a month of time)

Comment: @jterrace So this means i can keep storing in free tier until i reach 5GB... but for a given month i can go above 5GB provided that at the end of the month the delta remains 5GB ?.. meaning i can add stuff above 5GB and remove stuff at the same time to bring it to 5GB ?

Comment: If I understand correctly, I can have 1GB in there for 5 months without being charged. Then on the 6th and subsequent months, I will be billed for 1GB-month every month?  OR does the counter reset every month?  In that case, 5GB can remain in there indefinitely without incurring charges.  I can't tell which one it is.

Comment: The pricing table that jterrace linked says that your _Monthly_ Free Usage Limit is 5 GB-months, so I think that it resets each month or is at least evaluated with a monthly window. This confused me at first, too (which is why I'm here), and I haven't come anywhere near the limit yet. I'm just reading the table.